# Storing variable via .text() isn't uptodate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `<span>` tags in a div that is removed when user clicks on them. Works fine.

I want to store the `.text()` inside that div in a variable. The problem is that the **updated** text doesn't get stored.

Click on a word to remove it in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tscv22za/2/).

As you can see, the `content` variable returns the old text, not the new revised one.

How can I store a variable with the updated text?

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(document).on("mousedown", ".hello span", function() {

        // don't add full stop at the end of sentence if it already ends with
        var endChars = [".", "?", "!"];

        jQuery(this).fadeOut(function(){
            var parentObj = jQuery(this).parent();
            jQuery(this).remove();
            var text = parentObj.find("span").first().html();
            parentObj.find("span").first().html(ta_capitalizeFirstLetter(text));
            text = parentObj.find("span").last().html();
            if ( endChars.indexOf(text.slice(-1))  == -1 )
            {
                parentObj.find("span").last().html(text+".");
            }
        });

        var content = jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.hello').text();

        alert(content);

    });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the question. Can you add what should happen on each click in the demo

Comment: @Tushar It's pretty simple. In the jsFiddle, click on the word `lorem`, then the alert box should display `Hello world`, not `Hello world lorem`. Does that make sense? It's the variable `content` that's faulty...

Comment: I got this error -Uncaught ReferenceError: ta_capitalizeFirstLetter is not defined

Comment: @thescion So, forgot to add that function, it's not relevant, see updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tscv22za/2/

Comment: Check [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tscv22za/3/). Is this what you want

Comment: @HenrikPetterson "It's pretty simple." I'm sure you didn't intend to, but try and avoid wording/phrasing that can be perceived as condescending to the person who is trying to help you.

Comment: @Tushar That is exactly what I want. Although I need the function I use in my fadeOut() -- do you know how to achieve this using my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code to get the new text should be moved inside the `fadeOut` callback. Once the animation is completed and element is removed, then the innerText of the parent element will be updated. At this time, the updated content should be read from the DOM.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/tscv22za/4/)

```
// Cache the element
var $el = jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.hello');

jQuery(this).fadeOut(function () {
    jQuery(this).remove();
    // Irrelevant code removed from here
    ...

    var content = $el.text();
    alert(content);
});
```

Here's another simple demo with minimal code that'll help to understand the code better.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/pxgokuvb/)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to debug your jsfiddle in chrome, and it looks like the priority of your code is like this:

1. declare on this event - `jQuery(this).fadeOut(function(){`
2. get the the current data of the div   `var content = jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.hello').text();`.
3. alert your data without changes.
4. calling the funcntion of fadeout

I think all you have to do is to call your alert and 2 from your anonymous function of fadeout

Answer (score 1):

Just put your alert inside the callback:

```
jQuery(this).fadeOut(function(){
  var parentObj = jQuery(this).parent();
  jQuery(this).remove();
  var text = parentObj.find("span").first().html();
  parentObj.find("span").first().html(ta_capitalizeFirstLetter(text));
  text = parentObj.find("span").last().html();
  if ( endChars.indexOf(text.slice(-1))  == -1 ) {
    parentObj.find("span").last().html(text+".");
    var content = parentObj.parent().find('.hello').text();
    alert(content);
  }
});
```